# Vanishing of $\text{Ext}^i_{X}(E, F)$ vs. $\text{Ext}^i_{\mathcal O_x}(E_x, F_x)$ for $E,F \in \mathcal D^b(\text{Coh } X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, derived-functors, coherent-sheaves, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme and $E,F \in \mathcal D^b(\text{Coh } X)$. Let $x\in X$ be a closed point. Then, is there any connection between $\text{Ext}^i_{\mathcal O_x}(E_x, F_x)$ and  $\text{Ext}^i_{X}(E, F)$ ? In particular, does vanishing of $\text{Ext}^i_{X}(E, F)$ for all $i\gg 0$ imply vanishing of $\text{Ext}^i_{\mathcal O_x}(E_x, F_x)$ for all $i\gg 0$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of the two $\mathrm{Ext}$ groups?

Comment: Doesn't this already fail for $E, F$ some twists of structure sheaves of a projective scheme?

Comment: I think you should be assuming $i>0$ here for there to be anything interesting and even then it fails for $E=O(-2)$ and $F=O(-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ (as far as I can see).

Comment: @Sasha: The two Ext in my questions are the ones as defined in the derived category of an abelian caregory: for the first Ext, the abelian category is $\text{Coh } (X)$, and for the second Ext, the abelian category is $\text{Mod } \mathcal O_x$

Comment: This is far from an answer (I think it should be ‘no’, but I can’t prove it), but the converse seems true, at least if the first Ext group is computed in $Mod(O_X)$ (I think it makes no difference) and $Ext^i_{O_{X,x}}(E_x,F_x)=0$ for $i \geq N$ with $N$ uniform in the closed point $x$.